# "Cannot find tag library descriptor" error in myEclipse

Tags: java, tomcat7, jstl, tomcat9, myeclipse

I imported a project from Github into myElcipse (latest version) and I'm using Tomcat 9.0 version for deployment. The project itself was looking for the Tomcat v 7.0, which wasn't in my system so I switched it to v 9.0 and it worked. But after that, I received the following problem :

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

My directory looks somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIQIA.png)

And [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X78Lv.png) are what the errors look like.

Now, I saw that you need to have the jstl files in your WEB-INF**->**lib folder. But there was no lib folder within my WEB-INF. Atleast, not according to this project. Can anyone tell me what changes I should make in order to rectify this error?

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUjvj.png) a sample code snippet that contains one of these errors.

Comment: Basically: Tomcat never provided JSTL, it was always supplied as an external library. The author of the project might have used Maven or dropped `jstl-impl.jar` directly into his `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` folder.

Comment: I cannot find the 2 jstl files, the page seemed to have expired, and the suggested soultion is for tomcat 7.0. I'm not sure it'll work for me.

Comment: You can find the jars on Maven, e.g. [jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.6) and [jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.4).

Comment: I've downloaded the file from jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl .
Where should I add it?

Edit: I added it by configuring a new build path and all the errors are gone. Thanks for the help.